# Bad first positionning of the Dialogs when the content is too large

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using material-ui^0.20 with react^16.2, and I have a problem when first showing up a `Dialog` which embeds a `Component` with too much content.

Here is a picture showing the problem :

[image]

And this is what should be showing up (and which is after closing the `Dialog` and showing it up a second time, or after a window resize, etc.)

[image]

Here is some source code reproducing the problem ([online demo here](https://react-y4kbyv.stackblitz.io), [and the source code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-y4kbyv)):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

import Dialog from 'material-ui/Dialog';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';

import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';

class BuggyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Random_pyramids.jpg" />
  }
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
  };

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({open: true});
  };

  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({open: false});
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <RaisedButton label="Buggy Dialog" onClick={this.handleOpen} />
        <Dialog
          title="Dialog"
          modal={false}
          open={this.state.open}
          onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
        >
          <BuggyComponent />
        </Dialog>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme({})}>
        <MyComponent /> 
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

Is there something I can do to avoid this problem ? From what I could observe, not having a component inside a dialog, but the whole dialog as a component seems to correct this issue, but it's not very convenient, and not always possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens here is this:
Popup opens, material ui tries to center it and to center it, it tries to figure out the height of the content. At this point, the image is not available, so the contents (the image) does not have a height.

Image loads. Image now has a height, but the dialog is already positioned so this does not help.

You could try pre-loading the image (which is basically what happens later when it's updated). A hack-ish way to do this would be something like this:

```
<RaisedButton label="Buggy Dialog" onClick={this.handleOpen} />
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Random_pyramids.jpg" style={{width: '0', height: '0', visibility: 'hidden'}} />
```

This loads the image in an invisible img tag so the image is already loaded when the Dialog opens. The problem is that there is no guarantee that the image is loaded by the time the user clicks the button.

An alternative to this would be to detect when the image is loaded and then reposition the dialog. This works, but the downside is that once the image is loaded the dialog will jump, which may or may not be a problem.

```
class BuggyComponent extends Component {
    reRender() {
        this.props.dialog.forceUpdate();
    }

    render() {
        return <img onLoad={() => this.reRender()} src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Random_pyramids.jpg" />
    }
}

<Dialog
    ref="dialog"
    repositionOnUpdate
    title="Dialog"
    modal={false}
    open={this.state.open}
    onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
>
    <BuggyComponent dialog={ this.refs.dialog} />
</Dialog>
```

A third option that only works when the height of the image is known is to explicitly set the height of the img-tag. This also prevents the need for a re-render when the image is loaded, but you will need to know the size beforehand.

A fourth option would be to change the function that opens the modal so that function preloads the image (if needed) before trying to open the modal.

The fifth and hopefully working option would be to make the custom component scrolling fixed size. This solves the problem of the unknown height, but requires you to determine what is a good fixed height which may or may not make sense depending on the content. To avoid having to worry too much about screen sizes, the height is expressed in vh.

```
class BuggyComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div style={ {height: '70vh', overflow: 'scroll'} }>
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Random_pyramids.jpg" />
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually this happens with text contents, I just used an image because it was easier to reproduce. Maybe the issue is similar in my case, for some reason material-ui cannot compute the content size properly. But what concerns me a bit, is that this is only happening when the data is in an external Component embbed within the Dialog, and not when it's directly within the Dialog

Comment: Do you have the same problem of the data not being present at render-time?

Comment: Btw I indeed had a similar issue with images and fixed it using your fourth suggestion

Comment: Hmm no. The data is coming from an external service, but at render time I have everything needed within the component's state

Comment: Or for some reason, since it's within an external component, material-ui does not recompute correctly its size when showing up the Dialog ? The data is dynamic and changed from external tools, and the first time the Component is instanciated, it has no data. Maybe I need to change its key when I get new data to invalidate it and force a full rerender ?

Comment: I guess I can try to reproduce it with a `timeout`

Comment: If the second option, repositioning after loading, is acceptable, you could listen to componentDidMount in your custom component then trigger a re-render. Other than that (and setting a fixed height), I'm not coming up with any better answers. Hard to do without any testable code.

Comment: Personally I would probably try for a fixed scrollable height (preferrably expressed in vh, to make it more mobile-friendly) if the repositioning option is not an option. I think I remember having a similar issue, so it might be a problem with mui

Comment: I'll try the fixed height trick tomorrow. Please edit your answer so that I can accept it if it fixes the problem :)

Comment: Fixed height option added and will hopefully solve your problem :)

Comment: Well, that fixes the problem but this is clearly a hack I do not like much. Anyway I will consider it fixed. Thanks for your time !

Comment: There's rarely a pretty solution to an ugly problem (the way mui renders/positions its dialogs). Could be that there is a way to pre-render so that the actual rendering is fast enough for the positioning to work, but without seeing your actual problem it's a little hard to tell. Feel free to update with the actual code and I'll take a look :) If you do, write a comment so I get pinged

Comment: In this case, both using a fixed height and triggering a render (with `forceUpdate()` of the parent (the dialog) did the trick, but after discussing about it, fixing the size seemed better (from a user point of view)